# Why is dhclient being killed when attempting to obtain IPs for hundreds of interfaces?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface, dhcp

My objective is to create hundreds of macvlans on a single host and then obtain DHCP IP addresses for all of them. I created around 250 macvlan interfaces successfully. This seems to work for the first 200 or so interfaces, but after a while dhclient gets killed and the last number of interfaces never get IP addresses.

An example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

INTERFACE_BASE_NAME="unprotected"
NUM_DEVICES=250
INTERFACE="enp2s0"

make(){
        for ((i=0;i<NUM_DEVICES;i++))
        do
                INTERFACE_NAME="${INTERFACE_BASE_NAME}_${i}"
                echo "Creating $INTERFACE_NAME"
                ip li add link $INTERFACE $INTERFACE_NAME type macvlan
                ip link set dev $INTERFACE_NAME up
                dhclient -v $INTERFACE_NAME

        done
}
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: What are your ip/netmask? A `/24` only has 254 IPs.

Comment: @waltinator Network is `192.168.1.1/20`